# Dynamic text field properties settings in ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have created a 3d wall and I'm passing images and linking through xml. Now I have added the description, but it just displays in the middle.  I don't know how to align it.  On mouse over, the description of that photo should display there itself, but it is not displaying in the middle (for all the photos).

Here is my complete code:

```
var name1:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(name1);

var xmlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("XML/ImagesData01.xml"); // rename to your file!!!
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

function imagerollover(e:MouseEvent):void
{
//var mXML:XML;
name1.text = myXML.data[Number(e.currentTarget.name)].@description;  

//var imagesprite:Sprite = e.target as Sprite;
//if(showimage == true) {

}
```

How can I do this?
[image]

i have attached the image, highlighted the oval, text is displaying there itself, but i want it to be displayed on each image wherever i take mouse over

```
`stop();

 import fl.transitions.Tween;
 import fl.transitions.easing.*;
 import flash.display.Sprite; 
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

import org.papervision3d.scenes.*;
import org.papervision3d.cameras.*;
import org.papervision3d.objects.*;
import org.papervision3d.materials.*;
import org.papervision3d.materials.BitmapMaterial;
import flash.text.TextField;


var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.x = 0;
container.y = 0;
addChild(container);

var scene:Scene3D = new MovieScene3D(container);
var cam:Camera3D = new Camera3D();
var new_zoom:Number;
cam.zoom = 6;

var planedictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var imageplane:Plane = new Plane();
imageplane.visible = false;
cam.target = imageplane;

var maxRows:Number = 1;
var yaxis:Number = 0;
var anglenumber:Number = 100;

var image = new Array();
var urllink = new Array();
var urltarget:Array = new Array();
var planes = new Array();

var i:Number;
var max:Number;
var li:Number = 0;
var center:Number = 6.4;
var zoom:Number = 10;
var cameramove:Boolean = true;
var camerapositionX:Number;
var camerapositionY:Number;
var showimage:Boolean = true;
var imageholder;
var xposition:Number;
var yposition:Number;
var zoomdistance:Number = 12;
var name1:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(name1);
name1.x = 100;
name1.y = 20;
name1.textColor = 0xffffff;




var XML_Load:XML = new XML();
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("XML/ImagesData01.xml"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imagecontainer);

function imagecontainer(e:Event):void  {
    XML_Load = XML(e.target.data);
    max = XML_Load.data.length();
    var displayimage:Number = Math.ceil(max/1);
    var anglenumberMath:Number = ((Math.PI*2) * maxRows) / max;

    for(i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        image.push(XML_Load.data[i].@imagepath.toString());
        urllink.push(XML_Load.data[i].@url.toString());
        urltarget.push(XML_Load.data[i].@target.toString());

        var bfm:BitmapFileMaterial = new BitmapFileMaterial("IMAGES/" + XML_Load.data[i].@imagepath.toString());
        bfm.oneSide = true;
        bfm.smooth = true;

        var plane:Plane = new Plane(bfm, 130, 105, 1, 1);
        scene.addChild(plane);
        planes.push(plane);



        var planeMC:Sprite = plane.container;
        planeMC.name = "" + i;
        planedictionary[planeMC] = plane;

        planeMC.buttonMode = true;
        planeMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, imagerollover);
        planeMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, imagerollout);
        planeMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, imagepress);

        camerapositionX = ((150 * displayimage) - 150) * 0.5;
        camerapositionY = ((115 * maxRows) - 115) * 0.5;

        plane.x = li * 150 - camerapositionX;
        li++; 
        plane.y = yaxis - camerapositionY;

        if((i+1) % displayimage == 0) {
             li = 0;
             yaxis += 115;
        }
    }
};


var xmlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("XML/ImagesData01.xml"); // rename to your file!!!
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
//var myXML:XML;





//-----------------


//xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded); // event listener b4 load!!!
//xmlLoader.load(xmlReq);

//var myXML:XML;
//var mySprite:Sprite;
//var headLoader:Loader;


//function imagerollover(e:MouseEvent):void  
//{
//navigateToURL(new URLRequest(String(myXML.data[Number(e.currentTarget.name)].@description)));

//}


//function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void{
//myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
//for (var i:int = 0; i < myXML.children().length(); i++)
//{
//headLoader = new Loader();
//mySprite = new Sprite();
//headLoader.load(new URLRequest(String(myXML.data[i].@description)));
//mySprite.addChild(headLoader);
//mySprite.name = String(i);
//mySprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, imagerollover)
//addChild(mySprite);
//}

//}


//-------------------


function imagerollover(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //var mXML:XML;
    name1.text = myXML.data[Number(e.currentTarget.name)].@description;  

    //var imagesprite:Sprite = e.target as Sprite;
    //if(showimage == true) {

    } 
    //};

function imagerollout(e:MouseEvent) {
    var imagesprite:Sprite = e.target as Sprite;
    if(showimage == true) {

    }
};








xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded); // event listener b4 load!!!
xmlLoader.load(xmlReq);

var myXML:XML;
var mySprite:Sprite;
var headLoader:Loader;


function imagepress(e:MouseEvent):void  
{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(String(myXML.data[Number(e.currentTarget.name)].@url)),"_self");

}


function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void{
myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
for (var i:int = 0; i < myXML.children().length(); i++)
{
headLoader = new Loader();
mySprite = new Sprite();
headLoader.load(new URLRequest(String(myXML.data[i].@image)));
mySprite.addChild(headLoader);
mySprite.name = String(i);
mySprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, imagepress)
addChild(mySprite);
}


}



stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, CameraZoom);

function CameraZoom(e:MouseEvent) {
    var newzoom:Number = zoomdistance + e.delta/5;

    if(newzoom < 3) {
        newzoom = 3
    }

    if(newzoom > 18) {
        newzoom = 18
    }

    zoomdistance = newzoom;
};

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);

function render(e:Event):void {
    cam.zoom += (zoomdistance - cam.zoom)/5;

    if(cameramove == true) {
        cam.x += (((stage.mouseX-(stage.stageWidth * 0.5))*2)-cam.x) * 0.05;
        cam.y += (((stage.mouseY-(stage.stageHeight * 0.5))*2)-cam.y) * 0.05;
    }

    scene.renderCamera(cam);
};`
```

Comment: The picture your trying to paint with your words isn't really coming across clearly, maybe a screenshot of your flash application would better illustrate your problem.

Comment: name1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER; ? Also use half the difference between the width of the image and the textWidth of the textfield to offset the textfield accordingly.

Comment: Try this : keep the width of the label same as that of the image and set the textAlign to "center".

Comment: how are you doing the 3d? are you using an engine? or just native flash z properties etc?

Comment: @ Adam, I have edited my code. Like that i am doing wall. As am learner, i just reffered many walls and did the coding. Now am stuck here please help me

Comment: @ Adam, please have a look at my code. please help me in this...

Comment: @Priya, I don't understand your question. Is it that it is not displaying on each image, or that it is not centered to each image? Clarify a bit and we'll try to help you out.

Comment: It displays in one place for all the images, but i want it to display on the image once my mouse over that image

Comment: @ mgPePe, hope you got my doubt

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your question is basically "How can i reposition a TextField?". So without anymore detail I will answer that.

The TextField object has an `x` and a `y` property that changes its position. Just set them to the values you want.

```
name1.x = 100;
name1.y = 20;
```

Comment: Actually if i give like this it will come in the same position , but when i take my mouse over image1, text should be on it and image2, text should on image 2...

Answer (score 0):

Set the x and y position within the `imagerollover` function.

May be this will works.

```
name1.x = e.currentTarget.x;
name1.y = e.currentTarget.y;
```

Comment: i have used this, but still the same :(

Comment: use e.target instead of e.currentTarget.

Comment: `var name1:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(name1);
function imagerollover(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 
 
 name1.text = myXML.data[Number(e.currentTarget.name)].@description;  
 
 name1.x = e.target.x;
    name1.y = e.target.y;
 
  
 } 
`
This is how i did. Still no change samething,,, :(

Comment: find out in which container you have added the image, and place your textField there.

e.trget.parent.x... I am not sure.